# Substring not sub stringing string, or rather, substring not working as it should

Tags: vb.net, string, substring

I'm working on an application where users can select some values previously presented to them, they will always have a specific form like this: `userData_North`, `userData_South`.

I need the part of the string that is after the `_`, so obviously I tried doing a substring like this:

```
Dim rightString = userDataVar.SubString(userDataVar.IndexOf("_"), userDataVar.Length)
```

Which I believe gets whatever is after the `_` and until the string ends. But it returns `Nothing` for some reason. What could I've gotten wrong?

Comment: what is the expected output? example: userData_North, the output is: userData?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can omit the second parameter and just get from start to end of string.  Since you supply second parameter, you should minus the starting position - as it is now, you're exceeding the length of the original string.

Comment: Correct, the second parameter is optional.  He should only need the first parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mistaken how the Substring works.  All you need is the following:

`Dim rightString = userDataVar.SubString(userDataVar.IndexOf("_") + 1)`

The reason it's returning `Nothing` is because you are starting halfway through the string and then asking it to go for the entire length of the string and you are going outside the range of it.

Comment: I have indeed, thanks for pointing it out, and your answer is correct, it works fine now. Thanks. What does the `+ 1` mean though?

Comment: The first parameter of `Substring` is asking for the starting index in which to retrieve the desired string.  By getting the index of the `"_"`, you are asking to begin the new string at `"_"`.  However, since you want to start at the position AFTER the `"_"`, you need to add +1.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The two parameters to [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are `startIndex` and `length` - it looks like you were expecting `startIndex' and`endIndex' (ala JavaScript's [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)).

It's actually throwing an `ArgumentOutOfRange` exception (as documented in this case), meaning you're probably running with `On Error Resume Next` or otherwise hiding exceptions - that always make debugging a lot harder (and isn't really great for production either).

As mentioned by others, there's also convenience method to just get the remaining length which seems appropriate for your use case. Otherwise, you'd need to subtract out the `IndexOf`.

As an alternative, you could also consider using [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - especially if you intend to discard the "_" separator (in which case you'd need to `+1` your `IndexOf`).

Comment: You are correct, `On Error Resume Next` is on, I should keep this in mind, thanks for pointing out, +1.

Answer (score 0):

You're about to get the North or South?.

```
Dim userDataVar As String = "userData_South"
Dim startIndex = userDataVar.IndexOf("_")
Dim rightString = userDataVar.Substring(startIndex)
Dim getNorthSouth = rightString.Replace("_", "")
```